# In my app included 64-bit libraries but when i analysis apk it's still 32 bit

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.panache.fm"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

```
    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "77d104e0-6665-4288-a324-b74296fe24d4",
                            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

    ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildTypes.each {
    it.buildConfigField 'String', 'SERVER_URL', SERVER_URL
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/assets', 'src/main/assets', 'src/main/res/drawable-hdpi', 'src/main/res/drawable-mdpi', 'src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi', 'src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi', 'src/main/res/values-sw600dp', 'src/main/res/values-sw720dp-land', 'src/main/res/values-v14', 'app/libs/armeabi', 'libs/armeabi', 'libs/armeabi-v7a', 'src/main/jniLibs', 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi', 'src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a', 'libs/mips', 'libs/x86']
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation project(path: ':slider')
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation project(path: ':RadioLibrary')
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.2'
    implementation 'com.labo.kaji:relativepopupwindow:0.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.1'
    implementation 'fr.baloomba:viewpagerindicator:2.4.2'
    implementation 'com.github.iammert:MaterialIntroView:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:preference-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation project(':library')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your gradle to this:

```
    android { 
           compileSdkVersion 29 
           defaultConfig { 
           applicationId "com.panache.fm" 
           minSdkVersion 16 
           targetSdkVersion 29 
           versionCode 4 
           versionName "1.3" 
           multiDexEnabled true 
           testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

            manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "77d104e0-6665-4288-a324-b74296fe24d4",
                                    // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                    onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        }

    splits {
            abi{
                enable true
                reset()
                include 'x86_64','x86','armeabi','armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a'
                universalApk true
            }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

**Update**

It seams that this two configuration can't be set together. So you have two options:

1. Disable splitting APK (you've figured it out already). Than you will have one APK.
2. Remove `ndk.abiFilters` setting. Than you will have multiple (probably much smaller) APKs. Moreover, with `universalApk` true, an universal APK with all architectures will be generated (probably much larger than in option 1).

Comment: Just remove `mips`

Comment: when add i got this ERROR: Conflicting configuration : 'armeabi-v7a,x86_64,arm64-v8a,x86' in ndk abiFilters cannot be present when splits abi filters are set : x86_64,x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi,arm64-v8a

Comment: @MahmudulHasan as error says you have two cofiguration that have conflict. Then as I update my answer you need remove ndk.abiFilters settings.

Comment: after remove ndk.abiFilters app will not open app has been crashed every time here is logcat: 
11-16 11:30:44.988 20298-20317/com.panache.fm E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: INVALID_SENDER
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.panache.fm-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.panache.fm-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libaacdecoder.so"

Comment: can you analyse your apk and check .so file generate for 64bit?

Comment: Try clean and rebuild project.

Comment: Thank you so much release apk working fine but debug apk not working, anyways i need only release apk  Thanks